# Access last visit time to a post

Tags: posts, date-time

Is there any function or a way to access the time of last visit to a post by a visitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a small script in your single.php that updates a custom field with the current time.

```
update_post_meta(get_the_ID(),"last_visit",time());
```

Comment: Of course, that will update when *anyone* views it, so you could simply end up logging the last time you viewed the content yourself. Google/other-searches would likely also count.